# HttpClient PostAsync does not respond when internet is disconnected

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I have a xamarin forms app, where the app performs a `PostAsync` call to upload an image as multipartcontent.

The problem is in iOS device that when I switch off the wifi/ mobile data during the PostAsync call, the HttpClient doesnt go into the catch block to indicate an exception. It only does so after the default timeout of 100 seconds.

However this problem doesn't occur in Android, and succesfully goes in the catch block, indicating `System.IO.IOException`

This is my code which performs the `PostAsync` call, Did  I miss anything or do something wrong. Thank you.

```
 try{
 MultipartFormDataContent multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
 var uri = new Uri(string.Format(strUrl + "UserData/SavePointRequestData/", string.Empty));

 StringContent strPointsRequestIDContent = new StringContent(oPointRequest.PointsRequestID.ToString());
 multipartContent.Add(strPointsRequestIDContent, "strPointsRequestID");
 if (bImageData != null) {
  var PointRequestfileContent = new ByteArrayContent(bImageData);
  PointRequestfileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
  PointRequestfileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") {
   FileName = strActualImageName + ".jpg"
  };
  multipartContent.Add(PointRequestfileContent, "strUploadImage");
 }

 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, multipartContent);
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
  using(var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()) {
   using(var streamreader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
    var str = await streamreader.ReadToEndAsync();
    var obj = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync < string > (str);
    return obj;
   }
  }
 } else {
  return "Error1" + "," + oPointRequest.EventActivityName.ToString();
 }
 } 
catch (Exception ex) {
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);


  return "Error2" + "," + oPointRequest.EventActivityName.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Building with `NSUrlSession` or `CFNetwork`?

Comment: Setting the timeout to a lower value wouldn't solve the issue?

Comment: @SushiHangover Building with Managed(Default)

Comment: @Cyriac setting a lower timeout say 60 sec would cause the exception to occur after 60 secs, its would be good if exception gets fired similar to android, when internet disconnects...

Comment: @SushiHangover I changed it to NSUrlSession and it works, I get the correct exception also "The Internet connection appears to be offline".

Are there any downsides to this or is it the recommended method to set NSUrlSession ? Thanks

Comment: @NathanN On iOS I only use `NSUrlSession`, #1: Security as the Mono Managed provider only supports TLS1.0. #2: It is faster, period... uses less memory and produces a slightly smaller app #3: It is the main HTTP(s) provider within iOS and if it does not work then somewhere around one billion users would be really pissed off ;-)  #4 It handles iOS background fetches properly, the managed provider does not, it handles spotty cellular and wifi much much much better then the managed provider, etc.....

Comment: @NathanN That does *not* mean the HttpClient wrapper is perfectly written and it does not support 100% of the HttpClient's native features and the wrapper does not expose all the NSUrlSession features, but I code and test HttpClient using NSUrlSession from the start of a Xamarin.Forms project so I know of any issues sooner than later. Also when I code `Xamarin.iOS` native projects, I use NSUrlSession directly and skip HttpClient totally....

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks a lot , you've provided more insights then what I would have got from Apple /Xamarin itself :)

I'll definitely keep this in mind.

Comment: @Nathan N: Did you get any solution. What you did finally for this problem? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi sorry for the late reply, I used NSUrlSession