# Xamarin.ios: HttpClient GetAsync & PostAsync does not respond when network is disconnected

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When I am  trying to Get or Post a Json string from webservice which is a RestFul API using this code written in PCL:

```
try
{
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    cookies.SetCookies(uri, strCookie);
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 90);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return res;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

This code works fine on **Android** when internet is disconnected it immediately throws an exception, but in case of **iOS** exception is thrown after the 90s timeout value as specified instead of throwing immediately.

I refereed to following links but didn't helped:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51423

[HttpClient PostAsync does not respond when internet is disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169056/httpclient-postasync-does-not-respond-when-internet-is-disconnected)

I also changed the HttpClient implementation from **Managed(default)** to **NSUrlSession** of xamarin.ios project but still no change.

I also changed the above code implementation as:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But didn't solved my problem.